# Laravel how to retrieve specific value in array

Tags: php, laravel-4, polymorphism, eloquent

I have a polymorphic relation between organizations and ratings. My ratings table is set up like so:

```
id - integer
user_id - integer
score - integer
ratable_type - text
ratable_id - integer
```

Calling `$org->ratings` will retrieve an array with all ratings associated with that specific org. However, I only want to see if there is a rating with a specific `user_id` value.

Basically, I want to retrieve the rating with `user_id = Auth::user()->id`. Is this possibly without looping through all the ratings to see when `$org->rating->user_id == Auth::user()->id`?

Comment: You need to fetch the related ratings and then check or rather do simple check with db query?

Comment: I ended up using `Rating::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->where('ratable_type', '=', 'Org')->where('ratable_id', '=', $org->id)->first()`, but is there a more succinct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to load the relation, then simply query the DB:

```
$org->ratings()->where('user_id', Auth::id())->first();
// returns Rating model or NULL

// in previous versions of the framework (if Auth has no id method)
$org->ratings()->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first();
```

Otherwise filter the collection:

```
$org->ratings->first(function ($key, $rating) {
     return $rating->user_id == Auth::id();
});
// like before: Rating model or NULL
```

Comment: Using `$org->ratings()->where('user_id', Auth::id())->first();` worked.